# how can i get msbuild to build my c++ project the same as vs2013

Tags: visual-c++, msbuild

I'm trying to inject some compile time properties into a vs2013 c++ project like this

In the vcxproj file I have added and defaulted INCREMENT_BUILD_VERSION like so:

```
  <Project> ...
  <PropertyGroup>
       <IBN>INCREMENT_BUILD_VERSION=666</IBN>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and use it like this:
in the compiler section

```
<ClCompile> ... 
<PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;NDEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions);$(IBN)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
```

and in the resource section

```
<ResourceCompile> ...
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>NDEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions);$(IBN)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
```

and I then use the defaulted property in the header file:

```
#define PG_MAJOR_VERSION 6
#define PG_MINOR_VERSION 1
#define PG_MICRO_VERSION 22
#define PG_BUILD_VERSION INCREMENT_BUILD_VERSION <--- property from vxproj

#define PG_BUILD_ALL_STR_VERSION STRINGIZE(PG_MAJOR_VERSION) "." STRINGIZE(PG_MINOR_VERSION) "." \                                   STRINGIZE(PG_MICRO_VERSION) "." STRINGIZE(PG_BUILD_VERSION)

#define PG_BUILD_ALL_FILE_VERSION PG_MAJOR_VERSION,PG_MINOR_VERSION,PG_MICRO_VERSION,PG_BUILD_VERSION
#pragma message("INFO: SETTING BUILD VERSION TO " PG_BUILD_ALL_STR_VERSION)
```

When I build this in the ide everything works splendidly and I get the #pragma message
INFO: SETTING BUILD VERSION TO 6.1.22.666

However, as soon as I try and build this through msbuild.exe 
C:\Progra~2\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild sol.sln /p:Configuration="Release" /t:Rebuild

I get an error from the resource compiler about INCREMENT_BUILD_VERSION missing
and from the compile #pragma I get the message

INFO: SETTING BUILD VERSION TO 6.1.22.INCREMENT_BUILD_VERSION

I guess I've not defined the property correctly and msbuild is ignoring it but its ok in the IDE.

Anyone any ideas?

TIA.

Comment: Hard to guess at.  Get this working first without hacking the vcxproj file yourself.  Project + Properties, Resources, General, Precompiler Definitions settings.  Repeat for every configuration.

Comment: That should work -- I am doing the same thing with my projects and they work fine, both in VS and from command line. Make sure you: 1) Modified correct Platform/Configuration block, as you are invoking from command line; 2) You make your custom modifications before `<Import>`ing standard targets/props files, e.g. $(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props.